# How can I force file ordering in F# projects using vscode?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work with vscode in my WebSharper project (Ionide plugin seems... Whoah!) but when I load the fsproj into vscode, files in the explorer are ordered by name, not by "F# precedence". How can I configure vscode so that files are correctly ordered? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in VS Code for the Folder display. The easiest is to name the files in alphabetical order.... You can change the real ordering of the files in fsproject by using `F# Move File Down` or `Move File Up` (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Comment: Renaming files only to get the desired order is a solution but any time that I require to insert a new fs between existant files I need to rename a lot of files...

Comment: Another approach is to prefix the files with 100,200,300... Then you can insert files between 100 and 200 by prefix with 110.

Comment: You can change file compilation order in project.json

Comment: I'm building my project with Fake. In project file, files are correctly ordered, but in the solution navigation, they're not. I can work with that but it would be better if files were ordered as in Visual Studio (no code).

Comment: you might be in luck though, as it seems it's going to be possible: [VSCode PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/14048)

Comment: Is there any update on this to make it possible to have the explorer in correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS-like project explorer has been added to Ionide recently. It includes assembly references, project references, and ordered files (including folder supports). We've also added several commands to manipulate project and file order, you can access them with right-click context menu on this new project explorer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code you press Ctrl + Shift + P, then enter "F#: Move File Up".

Answer (score 0):

If you have activated the **great ionide plugin** you can navigate to the F# symbol on the activity bar. This will open the project explorer which allows you to reorder files using the arrow icons:

[image: Order files in project explorer]

This will *change the order of the files* (`<Compile Include="xyz.fs" />` statements) in your .fsproj file (which is what you would have to do manually if you're not using the ionide plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Without any plugin, VSCode 1.66 (March 2022) should support a better order support.

See [issue 32592](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32592):

> ordering of files is really important for the F# projects, and we provide couple of helper commands to manage it (move file up/down etc).
> Those commands work more or less, but I don't think it's best UX.
>
> I think it would be super nice if users had **ability to use normal drag and drop to manipulate the order** - just as they are able to manipulate files in normal file explorer (drag and drop files to move them to subfolder for example)

It is currently released in [VSCode insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), with [commit c468903](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c468903ff7ce5c0bec25b50648a3b23d557febcb) ("Finalize tree drag and drop API").